How to create unsigned Int property?
I need a property that can accept the 2267538950 number, unfortunately by default Blender uses a signed int range. There was a way to set subtype="UNSIGNED" in the previous versions but it doesn't work anymore(?) and I get an error
value not in 'int' range ((-2147483647 - 1), 2147483647)
bpy.types.Scene.vertInt1 = IntProperty(
 name="Integer",
 description="Enter an integer",
 default = 2,
 subtype='UNSIGNED')


Python int can accept any size limited by memory as far as I know, so int in [-inf, inf] in documentation for maximum value (https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.IntProperty.html) seems to make sense. I would report this as a bug or ask on devtalk forums. At least the documentation is wrong... In any case why do you need this?

I import values from a mesh format that uses uint for certain values and would be great to import them as is without an extra step with conversion them to something else just for blender

Okay I found it kinda works if you do it as simple code, but in the property group class where I need it, it raises this error

It did not work in any IntProperty I tested it on...

I handle this by converting to a string.
